# Why doesn't the standard Java iterator have peek()?

Tags: java, iterator

Is there any particular reason the basic Java iterator was programmed not to have a function like peek(), which would return the next element without advancing the iterator?

Comment: Ummm, because it doesn't. That seems like an impossible question to answer satisfactorily.

Comment: Guava has a peeking iterator, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the peeking iterator and it's a bit surprising peek() is not in the standard Java iterator.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as to "why", but for those who landed on this page looking for such an iterator, I can recommend https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#peekingIterator-java.util.Iterator-

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Why doesn't the standard Java iterator have peek()?

1. Because `peek()` is not part of the [Iterator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) as it is normally described.
2. Because the vast majority of iterator use-cases don't require it.  Forcing all implementations (including a myriad custom / 3rd party classes) to implement an unnecessary method would be a bad idea.
3. Because the `peek()` method has potential impacts on the semantics for iterators of lazy data sources.
4. Because implementing `peek()` affects the efficiency (memory, CPU) of a iterator in some circumstances.   Whether you actually use it or not.
5. Because `peek()` would in some obscure circumstances lead to a memory leak.
6. Because ... [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

But ultimately, the real reason is ... because they designed it that way back in the year ~2000.  And we weren't in the room when the design debates took place<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - For what it is worth, it seems that most<sup>2</sup> other languages have made the same decision for their standard iterator API.  Rust seems to be an exception to this; see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html.</sup>

<sup>2 - ... based on a highly non-scientific "survey" using Google search.</sup>

---

If you want an iterator abstraction that provides `peek()` as well, you can extend the `Iterator` interface and implement the iterators for yourself.  Indeed an general purpose iterator-with-peek can easily be implemented as a wrapper for a regular `Iterator`.

Or look for a 3rd-party API / implementation(s); e.g. [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html), [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/PeekingIterator.html), etc.

Comment: 7. Because it wouldn't be atomic.

Comment: That is a property of an implementation of `Iterator`.

Comment: It could never be atomic by design. You need `hasNext()` to kind of fix the availability of the next element.

Comment: To the extent that that any kind of atomicity is meaningful ... it could be implemented.  But this is in the context that the `Iterator` pattern is non-atomic by design; e.g `if (it.hasNext()) e = it.next(); ` is not atomic if `it` is shared by more than one thread.  I reckon this renders the atomicity of `peek` to be moot.

Answer (score 1):

The following example implements an Iterator with a `peek` method.  The implementation of `remove` is left for the reader.

```java
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * An Iterator with a peek method for just one value.
 */
public class PeekIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
  private Iterator<T> iterator;

  public PeekIterator (Iterator<T> iterator) { this.iterator = iterator; }

  private boolean peeked = false;
  private T peeked_value = null;

  public boolean hasNext () { return iterator.hasNext () || peeked; }

  public T next ()
  {
    T value;
    if (peeked) {
      peeked = false;
      value = peeked_value;
    }
    else
      if (iterator.hasNext ())
        value = iterator.next();
      else
        value = null;
    return value;
  }

  public T peek ()
  {
    T value;
    if (peeked)
      value = peeked_value;
    else {
      peeked = true;
      if (iterator.hasNext ())
        peeked_value = iterator.next ();
      else
        peeked_value = null;
      value = peeked_value;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: `hasNext` has a bug. It should be `iterator.hasNext () || peeked`, since `peek` could consume the last element on the underlying iterator. Then the iterator is empty, but on the PeekIterator, that peeked element still needs to be consumed.

Comment: Its not enough to just add iterator.hasNext () || peeked,  because now if you peek when there is no next element, peeked will still be true. If you run a hasNext() following a peek when you are at the end of the iterator, you will get a true response.
The easy way to fix this is to add peek = false in the else statement when checking if hasNext is true:
public T peek ()
  {
   .
   .
   .
      if (iterator.hasNext ())
        peeked_value = iterator.next ();
      else
        peeked_value = null;
        peeked =false
      value = peeked_value;
    }
    return value;
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

If you really need an iterator with peek(), why not use a `LinkedList` as your initial datastructure? It provides `.peek()` and `.pop()` to retrieve the head.